# discord.py: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'get' error

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

i'm trying to make my first discord bot in python. It worked well, untill I wanted to add function, when bot greets new member on specific channel.

Here is my code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions


intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.',intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="chess with your mum"))
  print("Bot is ready")

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
  channel = client.get.channel(828249420784205824)
  await channel.send(f'{member} dolaczyl do serwera!') #in english: "joined the server!"

@client.event
async def on_member_leave(member):
  channel = client.get.channel(828249420784205824)
  await channel.send(f'{member} opuscil serwer!') #in english: "leaved the server!"

@client.command()
@has_permissions(ban_members = True)
async def ban(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await member.ban(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(f'Uzytkownik {member} dostal bana!') #in english: "got banned"

@client.command()
@has_permissions(kick_members = True)
async def kick(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason=None):
  await member.kick(reason=reason)
  await ctx.send(f'Uzytkownik {member} zostal wyrzucony!') #in english: "got kicked"

client.run('TOKEN')
```

And error:

```
2022-12-17 20:21:24 ERROR    discord.client Ignoring exception in on_member_join
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/Bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 409, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 16, in on_member_join
    channel = client.get.channel(828249420784205824)
AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'get'
```

I would be very happy if anyone can help me. Thanks

Comment: You can't get a channel vom cleint/bot you need to get channels from a guild object (a server).

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the [client.get_channel](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=get_channel#discord.ext.commands.Bot.get_channel) method instead of `client.get.channel`, which doesn't exist.